# Unity: Custom Editor for inherited Event Property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have this setup

```
public class SomeClassMadeByUnity
{
    public int someUnneededVariable;
    public UnityEvent someEvent { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild : SomeClassMadeByUnity
{
    
}
```

`SomeClassMadeByUnity` has a Custom Editor under closed source, but I want to expose `someEvent` in a Custom Editor myself.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Does it need to be a property? Properties are not serialized by Unity

Comment: As the class is provided by Unity (XRBaseInteractable btw) there's really not much I can do.

Comment: Then we probably can't do much from here either. For a custom editor you need to at least know the field names (not the public property, and not the one displayed in the Inspector but the actual field names). In case they are private you could of course brute force until you have the correct name but that's not something we can help here ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a need/use for a custom editor here.

The "issue" is that **properties are not serialized by Unity**. So a custom editor wouldn't help much. Even if you somehow manage to expose such a field in the Inspector any changes in it wouldn't get stored anyway

All you need actually would be a serialzed backing field like

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
    public int someUnneededVariable;

    // You probably wouldn't need the setter anyway 
    public UnityEvent someEvent { get => _someEvent; set => _someEvent = value; }

    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent _someEvent;
}

[Serializable]
public class MyChild : SomeClass
{
    
}
```

---

Or if you already have a custom editor for the parent type you could simply make sure that you pass in `true` in [`CustomEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomEditor-ctor.html)

> **editorForChildClasses**
>
> If `true`, child classes of inspectedType will also show this editor. Defaults to `false`.

Comment: Unity provides a custom editor for this class (XRBaseInteractable), but I don't want to show every property on the inspector, as I don't need most of them.

Comment: Maybe you should rather post your actual use case ..

Answer (score -1):

You can write a custom editor for your *MyChild* class instead, extending custom editor of *SomeClassMadeByUnity*. But that if custom editor of *SomeClassMadeByUnity* is exposed as public. So let's say *SomeClassMadeByUnityEditor* is editor script for *SomeClassMadeByUnity*, than you could do something like:

```cs
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyChild))]
public class MyChildEditor : SomeClassMadeByUnityEditor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();    // To execute OnInspectorGUI logic of parent class.
        // Do some exposing SomeEvent logic.
    }
    
    // Or if parent class uses CreateInspectorGUI instead
    public override VisualElement CreateInspectorGUI()
    {
        var root = base.CreateInspectorGUI();
        // Do some exposing SomeEvent logic.
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand that correctly this still would show every property of `SomeClassMadeByUnity` and I don't need the majority of those.

Comment: @MarekLegris Ah, I probably didn't get correctly your intention. So you can just inherit your *MyChildEditor* from *Editor* as you would normally make a custom editor.